# go exec command to many open files

Tags: go, exec

I create a cron to check if server is down or not for every 1 minutes. and if down the code will execute command for run `myfile.sh`. Inside `myfile.sh` I put code for execute `mod vendor` and `build main.go`

```
if isDown == true {
    rescmd, reserror := exec.Command("/bin/sh","-c","sudo MY/PATH/MYFILE.SH").Output()
    if reserror != nil{
        fmt.Println("error %s", reserror)
    }
}
```

above code working fine for me. But sometimes error says `to many open files`.

when an error occurs as above I try to run my `.sh` file manual using `sudo MY/PATH/myfile.sh` and server success to execute, but when I use `exec.Command` (waiting my cron for every 1 minutes to run it) server will display error `to many open files`

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: The program breached the file descriptor limit.  The code in the question does not in itself use a large number of file descriptors.

Comment: I'm just excute command from `.sh` file for `restart` golang services. So if the server down, they will be automatic restart

Comment: Do you have 1000's of command instances in flight? If not, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I create a cron to check if server is down or not for every 1 minutes. and if down the code will execute command for run `.sh`. and my `.sh` file will execute `mod vendor`  and `build main.go`

Comment: Can you run `ulimit -aS` to see how many open files your OS allows?

Comment: open files  (-n) 1024

Comment: Cron will run your commend every minute, even if the prior command hasn't completed. This could result is many instances of the command running at once until available file descriptors have been consumed. Under Linux you can run something like this from Cron: `flock -n /tmp/foo.lock my_command`